# WiFi connects, but no internet. How to.problemsolve?

Tags: 16.04, wireless

I'm at a place with shared Wi-Fi. Connecting works, but I get no internet connection (ping 8.8.8.8 gives me connect: Network is unreachable). I am not sure if the problem is on my end, what can I check to find out? I've never had issues before.
I'm using 16.04.

Thank you very much

Comment: I understand "shared Wi-Fi" as public Wifi (as in a restaurant or something?) Maybe you need to pass a login process first?

Comment: It's a shared area in an apartment complex. My documentation doesn't say anything about some process to login, just provides name/password. Obviously I will call them asap, but is there anything I can try in the meantime?

Comment: "I've never had issues before." does this mean on the same machine and with Ubuntu 16.04?

Comment: Did you open a browser (FF, Chrome, …)? To my experience it first redirects to some login page when connected with a "public" network.

Comment: To check the path the packets are taking and see where it gets cut off, please add the output of `traceroute 8.8.8.8` to your question.

Comment: Yes, I've used this exact PC in many different networks before with no issues. I do not get redirected to some login page.

Answer (score 1):

Try going to a random unused domain that you have never browsed before making sure to use `http://` and **not** `https://` - if you're in a [captive portal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Captive_portal) it will likely redirect you to a login page.

Comment: One good domain for that is [example.com](http://example.com), which is both useful in examples since it's reserved by IANA specifically for use in examples and which has a nice, consistent HTTP server.

Comment: Thanks @ChaiT.Rex now I can stop going to `coolijustconnectedtosomewifi.com` every time I go to the airport.

Comment: Doesn't work unfortunately, I'm starting to think it is some problem on their end. Thanks though